# ng-class access element text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this situation in a **AngularJS** app.

```
$scope.current = 'my elem';

<div ng-class="{active: THIS ELEMENT TEXT === current}">my elem<div>
```

Can I access div.text() inside the `ng-class` directive?

Comment: Not sure what you mean here, maybe make the question more clear.

Comment: so i want to add class active on my element if $('div').text() === current, so can I access the element.text() inside the ng-class?

Comment: from inside of ng-class?

Comment: the question is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of what you are asking, please find bellow a snippet of how to use `ng-class` to apply a conditional CSS class based on string comparision.

*If you type 'red' in the input box, the text become red*

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.content = ["blue", "red", "green"];
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .red_text_class {
    color: red;
  }
  .blue_text_class {
    color: blue;
  }
  .green_text_class {
    color: green;
  }
</style>

<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="value in content">
    <div ng-class="{red_text_class: value=='red',blue_text_class: value=='blue',green_text_class: value=='green'}">{{value}}</div>
  </div>
  <input ng-model="myText" />{{myText}}
</body>
```

Comment: yes, this solution is good, but its possible instead of  <div ng-class="{red: myText=='red'}">HAHAHAHAHA</div> to have something like red: element.text() =='red'

Comment: I think you come from JQeury background, this is not the way angularJS works. I updated my example with what you want, but I concider it bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

You can check against the text in the div by using the $element service:

html:

```
<body ng-app="test" ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-class="{active: innerText === current}">my element</div>
</body>
```

controller:

```
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('Ctrl', Ctrl);

Ctrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$element'];

function Ctrl($scope, $element) {
  $scope.current = 'my element';

  $scope.innerText = $element.find('div').text();
}
```

[plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JqvvAP4rqTRGFSOWPCJq)

Answer (score 0):

To do that you should probably add dynamically your text in your div like this:

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.current = 'my elem';
  
  $scope.text1 = 'my elem';
  $scope.text2 = 'my other elem';
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="App" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div ng-class="{active: text1 == current}" ng-bind="text1"></div>
  <div ng-class="{active: text2 == current}" ng-bind="text2"></div>
</body>
```